# Simular la pulsación de la tecla tab al cargar la página

Tags: jquery

Tengo una vista con dos opciones 1)Editar  2)Añadir

```
 <li class="active">{{ ( isset($subcuenta) ? 'Editando' : 'Añadiendo' ) }}</li>
```

En caso de Editar:
 El focus se coloca  SIEMPRE en input-subcuenta mediante tabindex="1"
 el siguiente código se desarrolla  al abandonar el focus input-subcuenta,que es el primer input que aparece en pantalla

```
$("#input-subcuenta").blur(function(e){
            //-- Comprobación de los datos.
           var data = { "subcuenta": $("#input-subcuenta").val(),
                                       id: function() { return $('#_id').val(); },
                                       "_token" : $("#_token").val(),
                                         "idsusc":$("#id_id").val()};
            $.ajax({
                   type: 'get',
                   url: '/subcuentas/exist',
                   data: data,
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function( subcuenta ){
                            $("#input-definicion").focus();
                            if(subcuenta==false){
                                $("#boton").css("display","none");
                                $("#zsubcuenta").css("display","block");
                                $("input-sub")
                            }else{
                                $("#zsubcuenta").css("display","none");
                                if( $("#input-subcuenta").val().length >4 ){
                                    dameGrupos();
                                }else{

                                }

                            }
                   }
               });
        });
```

Mi idea es que al cargar la página se produzca lo siguiente:

```
 <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    if(".activa")='editando'{
       //simulamos la pulsación de tab para dar el focus a definición y desplegar dameGrupos
    }else{
       //.activa será 'añadiendo' y entramos los datos
       // y al abandonar el focus el input-subcuenta se desplegará dameGrupos  
    }
```

Espero haberme explicado, gracias anticipadas

Comment: ¿Por que no le das directamente el [focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) al elemento que deseas?

Comment: A la atención de  Nicolas Oñate .Me he explicado mal, el focus ya está en input-subcuenta  mediante  tabindex="1" y lo que necesito es que lo abandone  al cargar la página , el código $("#input-definicion").focus();,le dá el foco a 'definición' sin desencadenar dameGrupos,  rectifico el contenido de la pregunta